# Animation tableView cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, uikit, tableview

I need to make an animation like this, so that when I was waiting for a response from the api, 3 dots jumped. And when the answer came cell increases as I write the text

I've attached two gifs like I need and I have now

need todo like this:

[image: need todo like this]

now:

[image: now]

---

the tableView

```
private lazy var chatTableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    tableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05490196078, green: 0.08235294118, blue: 0.1176470588, alpha: 1)
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.register(ChatTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "chat_cell")
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 212/255, green: 212/255, blue: 216/255, alpha: 0.1)
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return tableView
}()
```

---

The upperView is tabBar (where " Dialog" is labeled) and lowerView is where textField is

```
chatTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
chatTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: upperView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
chatTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
chatTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lowerView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
```

The ExtansionTableView

```
extension ChatViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        if let customCell = cell as? ChatTableViewCell, indexPath.row == 0, models[indexPath.row].isAnimated == false {
            customCell.label.startTypewritingAnimation()
            models[indexPath.row].isAnimated = true
        }
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath)
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chat_cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        cell2.label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-SemiBold", size: 14)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-SemiBold", size: 14)
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell2.label.text = models[indexPath.row].text
            cell2.copyTapCallback = { [self] in
                UIPasteboard.general.string = models[indexPath.row].text
                print("copy tapped")
                copyView = CopyView(frame: .zero)
                copyView.closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeBtnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                copyView.alpha = 0
                view.addSubview(copyView)
                setupCopyLayout()
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    copyView.alpha = 1
                })
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                        copyView.alpha = 0
                    })
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                    copyView.removeFromSuperview()
                }
            }
            cell2.dislikeTapCallback = { [self] in
                print("hello dislake")
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This is not helpful", message: " ", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            cell2.shareTapCallback = { [self] in
                let textToShare = [models[indexPath.row]]
                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
                activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
                      self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            cell2.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1170914695, green: 0.1740572751, blue: 0.2324690521, alpha: 1)
            cell2.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1)

            return cell2

        } else{
            cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "user")
            cell.textLabel?.text = models[indexPath.row].text
            cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white
            cell.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05490196078, green: 0.08235294118, blue: 0.1176470588, alpha: 1)
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: -1)

            return cell

        }
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

The TableViewCell

```
class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    var copyTapCallback: () -> ()  = { }
    var shareTapCallback: () -> ()  = { }
    var likeTapCallback: () -> ()  = { }
    var dislikeTapCallback: () -> ()  = { }


    var image: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "robot"))
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        return image
    }()
    
    lazy var label: TypewriterLabel = {
        let label = TypewriterLabel()
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.9921568627, blue: 0.9921568627, alpha: 1)
        label.textAlignment = .justified
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    var copyButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "copy"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    var shareButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.isHidden = true
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "share_chat"), for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "like"), for: .normal)
        button.isHidden = true
        return button
    }()
    var dislikeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "dislike"), for: .normal)
        button.isHidden = true
        return button
    }()
    
    @objc func copyTapped(){
           copyTapCallback()
    }
    
    @objc func shareTapped(){

    }
    
    @objc func likeTapped(){

    }
    
    @objc func dislikeTapped(){

    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(image)
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        contentView.addSubview(copyButton)
        contentView.addSubview(shareButton)
        contentView.addSubview(likeButton)
        contentView.addSubview(dislikeButton)
        
        copyButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(copyTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        shareButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        dislikeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dislikeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        copyButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shareButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        likeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        dislikeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            image.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20),
            
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,constant: 16),
            label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 70),
            label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor,constant: -50),
            
            copyButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            copyButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            copyButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 70),
            
            shareButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            shareButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            shareButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 70 + 40),

            likeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            likeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            likeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -25 - 40),

            dislikeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            dislikeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -10),
            dislikeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -25),
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```